# What's the cheapest way (to hire another person) to move furniture from Buffalo (NY) to Toronto (Canada)?

Tags: usa, canada, relocation

I must relocate just my expensive $3K USD office chair, which my employer bought for me. I kept — and can REuse — the manufacturer's original packaging.

***Rule out driving, crossing the border, and moving by myself or acquaintances.*** I care merely about price. I already know about DHL, Fedex, USPS (US Postal Service), UPS — but anything else cheaper? The moving company shall be trustworthy!

I don't care about delivery speed or time.